# How to open image href on a aspx page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, asp.net

When the thumbnail is clicked I would like the full size image to open on http//example.com/image.aspx instead of http//example.com/images/image.jpeg without creating an individual page for each image and editing each href. I know that this is possible with php but I was wondering if there was some way of doing it with javascript, jquery, asp.net, or...? If it is possible, (I maybe stretching it here), would it also be possible to run this on the master page for all thumbs? The thumbs have no class or id. Right now they are in straight html markup. I have searched for days and have found nothing that would even get me started on the correct path with the exception of php. I don't need the target blank if I could implement this because this would allow me to open the image on a aspx content page with full site navigation. Here is the code as of right now.

```
<a target="_blank" href="image.jpg/jpeg"><img alt="something" src="pictures/image_small.jpg/jpeg"></a>
```

A page from our site is http://backalleypics.com/PeoplesPages/Sa~Se/SarahShahiPages/SarahShahi1.aspx. An example of the php type is http://www.theplace2.ru/photos/gallery.php?id=47 I really don't want a gallery, pop up window, or light box. The purpose is to get ad views for each image click and have navigation on the page.

Comment: You say that you know that this is possible with php, but actually the example you give is make a different new page for every image.

Comment: You can use jQuery to change all the a links to a new window as you say, with your ads inside the the image to show it.

Comment: The example I gave is what I want, I don't know PHP but from what I have read there is a way to do what my example is doing dynamically without creating an individual page for each image. Here is a sort of tutorial that I found for what I am trying to do with JavaScript but I am not good enough with JavaScript to adapt it to my situation. http://mckennedy.org/blog/2009/05/31/use-javascript-to-dynamically-display-images/ Thanks - Brian

Comment: If you do not know how to do - what you believe that you know that can do, hire some other to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought that was what this site was for? Maybe I was wrong! Who should I hire? You?

Comment: This site it is for that, but you do not wish to hear anything - you all ready know. This site is not for build you up a job, or a project or anything like that, but to help you and boost your when you have stop somewhere. From the other hand you must know, that I understand what you know and what you can do or not - and I told you what your issue. You come here with a question that you all ready have an answer - this is not working. When you have a question you must first accept that you do not know the answer - except if you are a teacher and teaching with questions.

Comment: Thanks. I new this would be harder than I thought, that is why I asked. I think I am close with the example that I gave. I will keep playing with that. All you had to say was you didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an existing library that do that, like the: http://highslide.com/

There are also many others, some of them:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/thumbnail.htm

http://valums.com/javascript-image-galleries/

Comment: Thanks, but not really what I am looking for. - Brian